# Wix - Upgrade will old installation and install new one

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I want that my installer, if detect a old one, previously uninstall it and then launch the installation of the new one.

I've the following Wix XML:

```
<Product Id="16bf910b-3b0f-4240-914a-81526bce35f4"
       Name="MyProduct"
       Language="1033"
       Version="1.0.0.0"
       Manufacturer="MyCompany"
       UpgradeCode="6ba28d97-41de-4371-a236-b757b7840f7b">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

<Upgrade Id="6ba28d97-41de-4371-a236-b757b7840f7b">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0.0"
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  OnlyDetect="no"
                  Maximum="1.0.0.0"
                  IncludeMaximum="yes"
                  Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" />
</Upgrade>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallValidate"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When generating the MSI file, install it (version 1.0.0.0), it's ok.
Now I changed the `Product/@Version` to 1.0.1.0 and click on MSI again, at this point I get a messge : "A previous installation of this product exists, please remove it first ...".

How can I modify this behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Product@Id maps to the Windows Installer ProductCode property.  This Id must change from build to build in order to be a Major Upgrade.  You can set it to "*" to let the compiler handle this for you.

Comment: Doing that will uninstall previous installation and install it properly or just override existing files? (BTW it works, thanks).

Comment: That's a complicated questions that requires an understanding of the component rules and the default file version rules.  Generally, yes, but YMMV based on these rules.

Comment: I updated my Wix version to 3.5 and now with `MajorUpgrade` tag, this is done automatically. Thanks :)